# VCL CheckListBox pass selected Item and delete it

Tags: delphi, vlc

Hi guys I am a Delphi beginner and I have a simple question because finding something online for Delphi seems to be hard.

I have a CheckListBox and when I click on the checkbox of an Item I want to pass it to another form lets say form2 gets created. There I have 2 buttons:

1. Delete - it should delete the selected Item so the item where the form spawned on. How do I delete the selected Item?
2. Edit Entry - I need to pass the checked Item values to another form where I can edit the values and save it as a new one. How do I pass the values from the selected Item to another form?

Ty Faded.

Comment: Do you need a second form? Why not simply a context menu with items "Delete" (Del) and "Rename" (F2)?

Comment: I dont need a second form but I thought that it would be possible to do something like this with a second form. Can you explain what a context menu is or how to implement it=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a better approach:

1. Create a new VCL application.
2. Add a `TCheckListBox` control with a few items on it:

   [image: Screenshot of form designer. A single TCheckListBox control is present on the form.]
3. Drop a `TActionList` component on the form.
4. Create two actions: `aDelete` and `aRename`. Sets their captions to `Delete...` and `Rename...` and their hints to `Removes the selected item from the list.` and `Renames the selected item in the list.`.

   [image: Screenshot of the action list editor.]
5. Add the following code to their `OnExecute` handlers:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.aDeleteExecute(Sender: TObject);
   begin

     if CheckListBox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
       Exit;

     if MessageBox(Handle, 'Do you want to delete the selected item?',
       'Delete', MB_ICONQUESTION or MB_YESNO) <> IDYES then
       Exit;

     CheckListBox1.DeleteSelected;

   end;

   procedure TForm1.aRenameExecute(Sender: TObject);
   var
     S: string;
   begin

     if CheckListBox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
       Exit;

     S := CheckListBox1.Items[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex];
     if InputQuery('Rename', 'Please enter the new name:', S) then
       CheckListBox1.Items[CheckListBox1.ItemIndex] := S;

   end;
   ```
6. Add the following code to their `OnUpdate` handlers:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.aDeleteUpdate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     aDelete.Enabled := CheckListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.aRenameUpdate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     aRename.Enabled := CheckListBox1.ItemIndex <> -1;
   end;
   ```
7. Drop a `TPopupMenu` on the form. Name it `pmList`. Add two menu items. Set their `Action` properties to `aDelete` and `aRename`, respectively. This will automatically give the items the caption, hint, and hotkeys of the actions:

   [image: Screenshot of the popup menu editor.]
8. Now assign `pmList` to the check list box control's `PopupMenu` property.
9. Test the application. Notice that the context menu items are enabled only if an item is selected; otherwise, they are both disabled. (This is thanks to the `OnUpdate` handlers. It would be very sloppy of us to skip these. But notice that we still verify that an item is selected in the `OnExceute` handlers. In quality software, you always use both belt and braces.)

   [image: Screenshot of the application running, with the check list box's context menu visible.]
10. Of course, we must map the <kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> keys to the delete and rename actions. We could use the `ShortCut` properties of the actions, but that would make these keys delete and rename in this list even if another GUI control has focus, and that's very bad. Instead, we add an `OnKeyDown` handler to the check list box control itself:

    ```
    procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
      Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      case Key of
        VK_DELETE:
          aDelete.Execute;
        VK_F2:
          aRename.Execute;
      end;
    end;
    ```

Comment: Dude you are awesome I would never even know that there is a possibility like this. Really thank you for taking your time and posting this awesome answer. Comming from React Native there is much stuff on the internet, thats the thing that Delphi lacks the most in my opinion. Because in generall Delphi seems to be a great language with many possibilites.

Comment: @yesIamFaded, you are quite right.  AndreasR is a very active contributor here and frequently provides top-quality answers.

Comment: Thank you, @yesIamFaded. Yes, the VCL's actions are pretty awesome. To see this even more clearly, you can drop two `TButton` controls on the same form as in my answer and place them below the check list box, next to each other. Then set their actions to `aDelete` and `aRename`, respectively. You'll notice that these buttons too get the captions, hints, and behaviour from the actions. For instance, they will both be disabled until you select an item in the check list box.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a *selected* (highlighted) item and a *checked* item. `TCheckListBox.ItemIndex` is the index of the 1st *selected* item. If `TCheckListBox.MultiSelect` is `True` then multiple items may be *selected* so you would have to use the `TCheckListBox.SelCount` and `TCheckListBox.Selected[]` properties to discover all *selected* items. Also items can be *checked* but not *selected*, so you would have to use the `TCheckListBox.Items.Count` and `TCheckListBox.Checked[]` property to discover all *checked* items.